# React Native modal offsets content underneath

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog, push, offset

As in the title, I have a modal that is hidden until the user presses a button. The functionality works, but when the modal is hidden content in the same container as the modal is offset by the hidden modal.

I was wondering what the best way to approach this is. Should I have some code that applies display: none when the modal is hidden, or is there a better way?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { ActivityIndicator, ListView, Modal, Text, View, Button, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class GroceryList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false
        };
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>hi</Text>
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => this.setState({modalVisible: true})}
                        title="PURCHASE ITEM"
                        color="#841584"
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <Modal
                        visible = {this.state.modalVisible}
                        animationType={'slide'}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({modalVisible: false})}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                                <Text>This is content inside of modal component</Text>
                                <Button
                                    onPress={() => this.setState({modalVisible: false})}
                                    title="Add to cart"
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        height: height,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        //margin: 20,
    },
    modalContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    innerContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 30,
    },
})
```

Comment: Make sure you conditionally render your modal only if your 'open' state is set, otherwise all your styling that you set will simply apply and cause the issue you're experiencing. Alternatively you could just avoid applying styling around the modal and use them inside, apply it to the Modal's 'children' instead (only, not around it).